Expected payout riddle: How to keep signature collectors from forging?
I made up this riddle, but I don't know how to solve it.

Marissa owns a company that collects signatures. Marissa can only hire perfectly rational self-interested agents (as defined in game theory), and she needs to hire them to collect the signatures.
For an agent to actually collect a signature it costs them $3$, to forge a signature it costs them $1$, and Marissa will pay them $5$ for every signature.
Marissa can verify signatures but it entails going to the person's house and comparing their actual signature with the signature she was given. Because of this, she can't verify every signature since that would defeat the purpose of hiring the agents in the first place. So, she devises a plan.
She makes groups of $100$ signatures (let's call each group a job) and she will pay an agent $500$ for a completed job. She also requires an earnest payment of $x$ from the agent before taking a job. When the agent returns with $100$ signatures, she will verify $1$ random signature.
If any of the $100$ signatures are found to be forgeries, the agent will lose their earnest payment of $x$, and they will not get paid the $500$ for completing the job, so they will also lose the $3$ it cost them for each actual signature and the $1$ for every forged signature.
What is the smallest value of $x$ such that the agent will never forge a signature because the expected value of doing so will be worse than not.


You are looking for optimal $x$ from Marissa's perspective, but there is implicitly another variable to optimise from the agent's perspective, namely the number of signatures to forge; you might call this $k$.  So for given $x$ and $k$, find the expected gain for the agent, then for given $x$ find the optimal $k$ (which would be an integer), then for those $x$s where the optimal $k=0$ you choose the smallest (or just above the infimum).  Let us know what you try.

It looks as if you have set up the question so it is possible that $x$ is negative but not too negative (i.e. that Marissa can pay the agent a positive amount initially which is not returned if a forgery is found but is returned if no forgery is found) and still have the agent's incentive be to collect $100$ genuine signatures.  I doubt this is what you intended. Does "smaller" include "more negative"?

If the agent doesn't forge any signatures, s/he makes $200$.  We can compare that with forging one signature.  In that case, if the checked signature is not forged the agent makes $202$  If the checked signature is forged the agent makes $-x-298$ because the cost of collecting the signatures is not covered either.  If exactly one signature is forged the agent expects $0.99 \cdot 202 -0.01(x+298)$.  We want to find $x$ so this is less than $200$
$$0.99 \cdot 202 -0.01(x+298)=200\\
0.99 \cdot 202-2.98-200=0.01 x\\-3=x$$
So Marissa could pay them $3$ that has to be returned if the checked signature is forged, but it was going to be returned if the checked signature was not forged.  So she should set $x=0$ and just refuse to pay the $500$ if the signature is forged.

If I'm understanding this correctly, the agent gets back the $x$ they paid if they successfully complete a job, correct? If that is the case, here's my approach to the solution.
If the agent forges 0 signatures, then the expected value is $500 - 3(100) = 200$.
If the agent forges 1 signature, then if they get caught, they "get" $-[3(99)+1(1)+x] = -298 - x$, or in other words, they have to pay a penalty of $298 + x$. However, if they don't get caught, they get $500 - 3(99) - 1(1) = 202$.
Continuing this pattern, we can see that if the agent forges $n$ signatures, then if they get caught, they "get" $-[3(100-n) + n + x] = -300 + 2n - x$, i.e. they have to pay a penalty of $300 - 2n + x$. If they don't get caught, they get $500 - [3(100-n) + n] = 200 + 2n$.
Then, we can calculate the expected value like so:
\begin{align}
E[forgeries=n] &= \frac{n}{100}(-300 + 2n - x) + \frac{100-n}{100}(200 + 2n) \\
&= \frac{1}{100}[-300n + 2n^2 - nx + 2000 - 200n + 200n - 2n^2] \\
&= \frac{1}{100}[-300n - nx + 2000] \\
&= -3n - \frac{n}{100}x + 200
\end{align}
We want this to be less than the expected value of forging 0 signatures, so:
\begin{align}
-3n - \frac{n}{100}x + 200 &< 200 \\
-3n - \frac{n}{100}x &< 0 \\
-3n &< \frac{n}{100}x \\
-300n &< nx \\
-300 &< x
\end{align}
It seems that it would be possible for Marissa to pay the agents a positive amount, rather than having the agents pay her, and achieve the desired outcome. It also seems like any positive value of $x$, if we are treating it as a penalty/payment, will work for the desired outcome, since the expected value for forging any signatures will always be less than the expected value for forging 0 signatures.
If you need further convincing on this, take a look at the difference in expected value between forging 1 signature and forging 2 signatures.
\begin{align}
E[forgeries=1] &= \frac{1}{100}(-298-x) + \frac{99}{100}(202) = 197 - \frac{1}{100}x\\
E[forgeries=2] &= \frac{2}{100}(-300+2(2)-x) + \frac{98}{100}(200+2(2)) = 194 - \frac{2}{100}x
\end{align}
As long as $x$ is a positive value, it's clear that the expected value for forging 2 signatures is less than the expected value for forging 1 signature, and the pattern will continue in this way.
